# ValueError: sharex [1] must be one of ['all', 'row', 'col', 'none']

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10 
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(n):
    # display original
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # display reconstruction
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1 + n)
    plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

This code give me the error give below
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call

ValueError: sharex [1] must be one of ['all', 'row', 'col', 'none']

Comment: In `plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)` call, the thrid argument is the `sharex` argument, which should be either `all`, `row`, `col` or `none` and you passed `i+1`

Comment: @rafaelc are you sure the third argument is `sharex` not `index`? The code runs fine on my end though.

Comment: @QuangHoang Oops, I mistook `subplot` with [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) ;p

Comment: Well, that (`subplots`) is very likely what OP has in his code, instead of `subplot`.